# C++ evaluates underlying if condition in a while statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, operator-overloading, logic

I have a problem that when  c++ evaluates the while statement, it also evaluates the underlying if statement even if the while statement condition is not met.

ite_candidats is a custom iterator on a binary map tree. When there is no more nodes to visit, ite_candidat evaluates to NULL. So the while ends. But, I get a assertion failure from ite_candidats.clecourante() call, saying my underlying node is NULL. It shouldn't evaluate ite_candidats.clecourante() because it wasn't meant to get to it.

I ran the program in debug mode, and !!ite_candidats really evaluates to false when there is no more nodes to visit. If I comment out the if block, the program gets out of the while loop and everything is ok...

The operator overloading of ite_candidats operator bool() doesn't call clecourante().

```
while(!!ite_candidats){
    if(ite_candidats.clecourante() != nompersonne){
        {...}
    }
    ite_candidats++;
}
```

Comment: `while (false) expr;` will never evaluate `expr`, ever. You need to look back into your code a bit deeper, since your premise is not correct.

Comment: Step through a debugger or throw in a printf in your loop body and verify the body is not being called.  Just looking at the above code, I have my suspicions the loop body is called and your loop control is off...

Comment: If it gets into the loop, then `!!ite_candidats` is `true`. If it doesn't, it's `false`. Period.

Comment: I think you'll need to post a small, complete, compilable example that produces the problem. There's either something subtle in your code causing the behavior, you're misinterpreting something, or there's a compiler bug (unlikely, but it does happen). In any case, the details will be important.

Comment: I've added a cout << "clecourante" inside the clecourante() method. I then I saw clecourante all over my console (not normal). Then I changed the method name to getclef() instead of clecourante() and now I got a the wished behavior... If I get back to the clecourante() method, I'm back to case 1. I check all occurences of calls to clecourante() with a search in my workspace. For now I will keep getclef name, but that's weird.

Comment: @Lunfel: That is quite weird. Could you post the code of `clecourante`/`getclef`?

Comment: @Lunfel: set a break point on `clecourante()` in a debugger and see who is calling it unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible. If it evaluates `if` then it enters into `while`. No ahead computation is `C++`.

P.S. Why do you have two negations in `while`?

Comment: the double !! is a quick and dirty way to convert a non-bool value to a bool value.

Comment: Maybe the two negations is why the OP thinks it's falsely evaluating the if statement?  The while statement IS being called?

Comment: @Mike but what for he wants to convert `ite_candidats` to `bool`?

Comment: @Dims The only possibility I could think of is that ite_candidats has overloaded `!` operator, so it could be converted to a bool value only through double negation. Although I don't think I've ever seen that in actual code.

Comment: @Dims hard to say without seeing its definition

Comment: I did double !! to be sure I'd have a bool value. Easier to see what's going on when using the debugger with expression evaluation

Comment: @Lunfel, this is not clear anyway. You need not to convert to `bool` in `C++` it takes `0` and `NULL` as false automatically. Also you'd better write something explicit like `ite_candidats.hasNext()` or `ite_candidats != NULL` if it would a pointer.

Comment: Sorry for long wait. The problem wasn't c++ at all. It was with eclipse. I was using the expression watcher wich was creating side effets when I evaluated the value of .clecourante(). When I compiled in command line, I had different errors. That's how I figured the expression watcher what interfering.

Answer (score 1):

rough guess: ite_candidats is incremented in the code. probably the end iterator is not evaluating to 0.

Answer (score 1):

> ite_candidats is a custom iterator on a binary map tree. When there is no more nodes to visit, ite_candidat evaluates to NULL.

Does it really evaluate to NULL? That's a bit dubious since you are using the dot operator rather than the dereference operator in `ite_candidats.clecourante()`. From the code that you did post, it looks like `ite_candidats` is an instance of some object rather than a pointer to some object.

> The operator overloading of ite_candidats operator bool()

This, I suspect, is the problem. Your `!!ite_candidats` is going use that conversion operator to cast `ite_candidats` to a `bool`, negate that result to yield `!ite_candidats`, then negate again to yield `!!ite_candidats`.

The problem is that your `operator bool()` is checking for a condition different from the preconditions of `WhatEverYourCustomIteratorClassIsNamed::clecourante()`.